# How do I generate Label IDs dynamically in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I generate a label ID dynamically in ASP.NET MVC?

I was able to generate dynamic Ids for different TextBoxes using the following code:

```
 <% for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
   {%>
    <div>
     <%=Html.TextBox("F" + i, "", new { @class = "date", @value = "10/10/10", @style = "width:55px;  color:#00467f ;" })%></div>
   </div>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
<label for="F<%=i.ToString()%>" id="label-id-<%=i.ToString()%>">Label text</label>
```

Comment: This do Generate new id but i can't see labale id name in my controller public string save(FormCollectino form). I can see only my textbox id. Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: You do understand that FormCollection contains the data coming off of form elements which are submitted via post. Form elements include things like <input /> and <select /> but not <label />

Comment: Thanks you guys for very quick answer.